# Two different projects with common library in cmake

Tags: cmake

I want to create two applications with common code. Suppose to have a structure like this

```
root
 |-libcommon
 |-projA
 |-projB
```

But without `CMakeLists.txt` in the `root`.

The main reason is that I want to package `projA` and `projB` as separate packages (not two components of one project). But as far as I understand you can create only one package using `CPack`. Is I'm correct with `CPack`? And if so, how can I resolve my situation? Do I need to install `libcommon` system-wise?

Comment: "But as far as I understand you can create only one package using CPack." - For some cpack-generators it is possible to create per-component packages (according to `COMPONENT` parameter in `install()` command). "I want to package `projA` and `projB` as separate packages (not two components of one project)" - Well, so build them as separate projects, using each own `CMakeLists.txt`. I don't understand your problem.

Comment: @Tsyvarev First point is that "some" it isn't what I need. Second point is that `COMPONENT` doesn't allow to set different versions for each component.

And if I will use separate `CMakeLists.txt` how can `projA` found `libcommon`? Does it require to install library system-wise?

Comment: "how can `projA` found `libcommon`?" - With `find_package`. By default it works for system-wide installation, but you may pass additional parameters to `cmake` for search packages in other places too. It seems you want to have all *packages* separated. It is a good approach, just follow it. In that case "root" `CMakeLists.txt` simply doesn't need.

Comment: @Tsyvarev Is it correct, that in this case, I must manually create `Findlibcommon.cmake` or `libcommonConfig.cmake` in `libcommon` directory to make it avaliable to search? And specify build directory in it?

Comment: Create `libcommonConfig.cmake` file as described in the [documentation](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.7/manual/cmake-packages.7.html#creating-packages). After installing `libcommon` into (local) directory, pass this directory when configure `projA`: `cmake -DCMAKE_PREFIX_PATH=<libcommon-install-directory> ...(other arguments)`.

Comment: @Tsyvarev Thank you very much. Can you post your last comment as answer? Then I can mark it as a solution